# Can create a file using PHP, but it won't load on the browser for half an hour

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

So I'm making a browser based game, and in order to create an account for this game I have the JS file call a PHP file (POST) to write an XML file.

This works, I get the file in cPanel, in the right directory, with the right content. Meaning I can open it, but only in cPanel. When I try to access it via browser I get a 404, but only for about 30 min, then it'll just magically start working.

This same PHP file is called later on in the game to update XML files, and the same thing happens. I can confirm that the PHP works exactly as it should, because I can see that the file/directory is perfect.

Here's the interesting bit, if I create an XML file manually or update it manually, it works instantly. It's only the XMLs created by the PHP file that take forever to load.

It's like the server doesn't realize that there was a change on it, until half an hour after the fact. That is, unless I did it manually.

My PHP:

```
<?php
    $filename=$_POST['fileTo'];
    $newfile=fopen($filename,"w")or die('Can not open');

    $string=$_POST['stuff'];
    fwrite($newfile,$string) or die('Could not write');

    fclose($newfile);
?>
```

My AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: writeDirect,
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(result) {
    },
    cache:false,
    error: function(error) {
        $.post('PHP/Accounts/creatAcc.php', { fileTo: userWrite, stuff: writeStuff }, function() {
            signIn(userATFS, passCe);
        });
    }
});
```

Update:
I've decided to access the games directory directly from the browser. This gets even more interesting.

First thing I did was create a new account called testFile, I get the standard error on the GET because the game can't access the newly created account.

Then I opened the directory in Chrome, this is interesting:

[The index clearly shows that testFile.xml exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96PmG.png)

Then I try clicking on it, but this is where it breaks

[The images 404 despite the file clearly existing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUgAB.png)

And no, changing the permissions on testFile.xml did not change anything.

Comment: could be the file path or file permissions

Comment: Unless you are hosted on a VIC20 or your xml counts 10,000 lines, there is no reason for it to take a REALLY LONG time. Maybe watching the network in the developer console (ctrl shift J in chrome) during the request might shed some light.

Comment: @deg I looked at the network and everything seems normal. I think it's handling the requests fine, but it's like the server doesn't realize any file was created until about 30 min after. Any xml file that I create manually, however, shows up instantly.

Comment: Bloody hell that's like 25 times what I thought at worst.

Comment: You may want to start adding code to the question.

Comment: @deg Hopefully this is better.

Comment: Do you eventually fclose($newfile) ?

Comment: @deg Now that you mention it I did neglect to do that. I'm a noob in PHP, and although I did know about fclose, not using it didn't had any negative on my code before. Could that be it? I'll give it a shot in the morning.

Comment: And stop using `@` - this masks any errors you may be getting.  Especially when your having problems with the file and your not reporting errors on writing to it.

Comment: @deg I tried I updated the PHP with fClose and remove @ like Nigel suggested. Still the same thing.

I believe it has to be something weird with the server. I know that it isn't slow, because my manual files appear instantly, so it has to be something specifically regarding how it handles files created by the script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the answer. I think it was just that server that was weird like that. I was using x10 basic and decided to switch over to another service and now it works.